# Application crashes when using address sanitizer with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to use address sanitizer with MSVC.

Visual Studio Installer says I have "Visual Studio Community 2019" version 16.9.0.

I have the most basic C++ program:

```cpp
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt is also very basic:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled VERSION 1.0.0)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
add_definitions(/fsanitize=address /Zi)
```

The program compiles and links correctly, both in debug and release mode. In release mode, I have the following warning, which seems perfectly legit:

> LINK : warning LNK4302: please add '/DEBUG' to the link command line for better ASAN error reporting

So far, so good (?).

However, when I run the application, the return code is -1073741515 (0xC0000135). Google tells me this is likely to indicate a missing library.

If I remove `add_definitions(/fsanitize=address /Zi)` from the build, the return is 0. The missing library is very likely the address sanitizer itself.

How can I configure my system properly to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ASAN is a debugging feature. For this reason the `clang_rt.asan_*.dll` DLLs are not installed in System32 as part of the VC++ redistributable package.

As explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/#compiling-with-asan-from-the-console), when using ASAN in shared CRT mode (`/MDd`), you need to ensure `clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll` and `clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll` are on the PATH.

You can add `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64` to the PATH or copy the DLLs to your project's output folder (side-by-side with your .exe).

Prior to Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7 Preview 3, you could alternatively build in static CRT mode (e.g. `/MTd`) which would embed the ASAN lib into the .exe. Newer version of Visual Studio [always require the separate DLL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-address-sanitizer-one-dll-for-all-runtime-configurations/).

Finally, as the warning suggests, use ASAN with Debug build type for better coverage:
`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio 22 the location of the dll has changed. In my case I needed the i386 version. The location for `clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-i386.dll` is:

- Community x86: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\<version>\bin\Hostx86\x86`.
- Professional x64: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\<version>\bin\Hostx64\x64\`

This must be added to the PATH variable (or copied to the exe dir) to prevent this error. Take the 64 bit version if debugging for x64.

Comment: One can use the variable `$(VCToolsInstallDir)` for the path up to and including `<version>`. If it is not available in MSVS then add `$(VCTargetsPath)/Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props` to the project.

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to carry llvm-symbolizer.exe from the same folder. Sanitizer runtime is using it to symbolize the stack traces in case of errors found

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator has an option in settings that is enabled by default that adds proper environment variables from your toolchain, I guess VSCode CMake Tools extension does this too, I have used both,
anyways with CLion, I had to add this, I hate it is manual but yeah,

Go to File -> Settings -> Toolchains -> Visual Studio,
Then click on "Add environment",
Choose "From file"
and paste in the path to vcvars64.bat or other bat files in
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`
that match your build config, I really hope there is an automatic way for this

[image]