# Cmake install fails to fetch ASan on MSVC

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022, address-sanitizer

I've been trying to build lmms with sanitizers enabled on msvc (I'm testing an unmerged PR). I am getting this sort of an error after running `cmake --install . --prefix=(folder) --config=Debug`

```
-- Finding prerequisites of lmms.exe

--

warning: cannot resolve item 'clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll'

  possible problems:

    need more directories?

    need to use InstallRequiredSystemLibraries?

    run in install tree instead of build tree?

-- warning: gp_resolved_file_type non-absolute file 'clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll' returning type 'other' -- possibly incorrect

--

warning: cannot resolve item 'clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll'

  possible problems:

    need more directories?

    need to use InstallRequiredSystemLibraries?

    run in install tree instead of build tree?

--

warning: cannot resolve item 'clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll'

  possible problems:

    need more directories?

    need to use InstallRequiredSystemLibraries?

    run in install tree instead of build tree?

CMake Error at D:/BuildAndGit/lmms/cmake/modules/InstallDependencies.cmake:179 (message):

  Can't resolve dependency clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll.

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  D:/BuildAndGit/lmms/cmake/modules/InstallDependencies.cmake:126 (find_prerequisites)

  cmake/install/cmake_install.cmake:63 (INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES)

  cmake_install.cmake:112 (include)
```

Asked the PR author and he has no idea either. I can link the PR here if requested. I'm discussing this with the LMMS team but am looking for extra info.

I tried to get lmms build and installed using cmake. It builds fine but fails to install.

Comment: given msvc is marked experimental https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/wiki/Compiling#compiler it doesn't seem surprising that not everything works

Comment: Have you tried locating the `clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll` file and pointing the compiler to its location? See also [Application crashes when using address sanitizer with MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66531482/12345551)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I know it is experimental, I am a part of the team working on adding full msvc support. Also, sanitizer support too is unmerged as of now. I asked the devs and they got no clue either.

Comment: @He3lixxx I tried it one time, it didn't work but then I clean rebuilt after adding the dll's folder to path. I can confirm that it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer: Like He3lixxx said, I added the directory containing `clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll` to path (ie, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64`) one time but didn't work. I then ran cmake again and rebuilt clean, which fixed everything now.